# Rewrite array keys by matching it to first child key, possible in php?

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to match array key to logo_id?

If I cannot find a way to do this, I will need to use array search which can become quite slow with an array of 200 items. Right?

p.s. this is result returned by mysqli fetch result call. Maybe this can be modified to provide array which I need?

```
                                Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array
        (
            [logo_id] =&gt; 1
            [logo_name] =&gt; beeline
            [logo_level] =&gt; 1
            [logo_image_path] =&gt; logos/1.png
            [logo_value] =&gt; 2
            [logo_hints] =&gt; 
        )

    [1] =&gt; Array
        (
            [logo_id] =&gt; 2
            [logo_name] =&gt; geocell
            [logo_level] =&gt; 1
            [logo_image_path] =&gt; logos/2.png
            [logo_value] =&gt; 4
            [logo_hints] =&gt; 
        )

    [2] =&gt; Array
        (
            [logo_id] =&gt; 3
            [logo_name] =&gt; google
            [logo_level] =&gt; 1
            [logo_image_path] =&gt; logos/3.png
            [logo_value] =&gt; 5
            [logo_hints] =&gt; 
        )

    [3] =&gt; Array
        (
            [logo_id] =&gt; 5
            [logo_name] =&gt; coca cola
            [logo_level] =&gt; 1
            [logo_image_path] =&gt; logos/5.png
            [logo_value] =&gt; 2
            [logo_hints] =&gt; 
        )

)
```

Did I explain it good? phh, sorry for bad wording.

Comment: why not altering main array keys with `logo_id`?

Comment: @Akam Can you give me an example please?

Comment: `mainarray = array (0 => array(logo_id] => 1...))` to `mainarray = array (logo_id whic is 1 => array(logo_id] => 1...))`

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do here..?

Comment: @Akam I don't create array, I fetch it from db.

Answer (score 2):

> this is result returned by mysqli fetch result call. Maybe this can be modified to provide array which I need?

Yes. I assume you mean [`mysqli_result::fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). Use [`mysqli_result::fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) in a loop instead and construct your array manually with whatever keys you like to.